# Having issues with hiding and showing divs on an onchange

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am having issues firing off an on-change in the department drop-down field not sure if i wrote it correctly. The error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. I am trying to select a department like claims then it will fire off an onchange to show another drop-down called workrequested. I have not filled all the departments yet but that should not mater if i want to test it on couple departments first. I think it has to do with dvPassport1.style.display

```
   <script>
  function ShowHideDiv1() {
        var Department = document.getElementById("Department");
        var divPassport1 = document.getElementById("divPassport1");
        divPassport1.style.display = Department.value == "Claims" || Department.value == "Flat 1"|| Department.value == "Flat 2"|| Department.value == "Hanging Bulk" || Department.value == "Hanging Store North" || Department.value == "Hanging Store South" || Department.value == "Inventory Integrity" || Department.value == "Rack Shoes" || Department.value == "Fine Jewelry"? "block" : "none";
    }
     function ShowHideDiv2() {
        var Department = document.getElementById("Department");
        var divPassport2 = document.getElementById("divPassport2");
        divPassport2.style.display = Department.value == "JackPotLane" ? "block" : "none";
    }

    </script>
<?=form_open('insert/create/', array(
'class' => 'form-horizontal',
'role' => 'form',

)); ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<h3>Validation Form</h3>

<br>
  <div class="col-sm-6">


   <div class="form-group">
     <?php echo form_label('ZID', 'ZID', $attributes=array());?>
     <?php echo form_input('ZID', set_value('ZID'), $attributes=array("class" => "form-control", "id"=>"ZID"));?>
     <!--show error message -->
      <div class="error"><?php echo form_error('ZID'); ?></div>
   </div>



    <div class="form-group">
     <?php echo form_label('Employee Name', 'EmpName', $attributes=array());?>
     <?php echo form_input('EmpName', set_value('EmpName'), $attributes=array("class" => "form-control", "id"=>"EmpName"));?>
      <!--show error message -->
   <div class="error"><?php echo form_error('EmpName'); ?></div>
   </div>





    <div class="form-group">
     <?php echo form_label('Department', 'Department', $attributes=array());?>
     <?php 
     $options = array(
        ""=>"Choose Department",
        "Claims" => "Claims",
        "Flat 1"=>"Flat 1");
     ?>
     <?php echo form_dropdown('Department', $options,set_value('Department'),array("class" => "form-control", "id"=>"Department", "onchange" => "ShowHideDiv1();ShowHideDiv2();"));?>

     <!--show error message -->
   <div  class="error"><?php echo form_error('Department'); ?></div>
   </div>




    <div class="form-group" id="divpassport1" style="display: none" >
     <?php echo form_label('WorkRequested', 'WorkRequested', $attributes=array());?>
     <?php 
     $options = array(
        ""=>"Choose WorkRequested",
        "Cases Not Received" => "Cases Not Received",
        "Master Pack"=>"Master Pack");
     ?>
     <?php echo form_dropdown('WorkRequested', $options,set_value('WorkRequested'),array("class" => "form-control", "id"=>"WorkRequested"));?>
         <!--show error message -->
   <div  class="error"><?php echo form_error('WorkRequested'); ?></div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group" id="divpassport2" style="display: none" ">
     <?php echo form_label('WorkRequested', 'WorkRequested', $attributes=array());?>
     <?php 
     $options = array(
        ""=>"Choose jackpot WorkRequested",
        "FYI" => "FYI",
        "Request"=>"Request");
     ?>
     <?php echo form_dropdown('WorkRequested', $options,set_value('WorkRequested'),array("class" => "form-control", "id"=>"WorkRequested"));?>
         <!--show error message -->
   <div  class="error"><?php echo form_error('WorkRequested'); ?></div>
   </div>




<div class="form-group">
  <?php echo form_label('Description','ReqDescription', $attributes=array());?>
<?php echo form_textarea('ReqDescription',set_value('ReqDescription'),array("class"=>"form-control textarea","id"=>"ReqDescription"));?>
     <!--show error ReqDescription -->
<div class="error"><?php echo form_error('ReqDescription'); ?></div>
</div>
 <input type="hidden" name="DATEREQUESTED" value="<?php echo date("Y/m/d h:i:sa");?>" value="<?=set_value('DATEREQUESTED')?> "  value="<?=set_value('DATEREQUESTED')?>"> 


 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="Status" name="Status" value="Received" placeholder="Status" value="<?=set_value('Status')?>">
<div class="form-group">
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', array("class"=>"btn-primary btn", "id"=>"submit"));?>
</div>


  <?php echo form_close()?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you want to get `divPassport1` (d**i**vPassport1) and `divPassport2` and not `dvPassport1` and `dvPassport2`.

Change `var dvPassport1 = document.getElementById("dvPassport1");` to `var dvPassport1 = document.getElementById("divPassport1");` and second one respectively or correct the ids.

**EDIT**
I guess you are accessing elements too early and you DOM is not loaded yet. Move your js code to the end of page before closing `body` and wrap it following way to wait for window onload event:

```
<script>
(function() {
   // your javascript code here
   // the DOM will be available here
})();
</script>
```

Comment: I changed it to correct ids but still get style error

Comment: i updated the form above maybe you can check to see if its correct